# i want 1 image in small screen in 480px then 2 image 580px then 3 image 768px then 4 image 980px

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to define 4 screen sizes and 4 variable values. I am trying as below.

```js
if ($(window).width() > 789) {
  var cyx = 1;
}
if ($(window).width() < 780) {
  cyx = 2;
}
if ($(window).width() < 580) {
  cyx = 3;
}
if ($(window).width() < 480) {
  cyx = 4;
}
```

Is it possible to do this a shorter way in Javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your code? It makes no sense at all.

Comment: i have this code below ....but i want to short this


  if ($(window).width() > 789) {
    var cyx = 1;
  }
  if ($(window).width() < 780) {
    cyx = 2;
  }
  if ($(window).width() < 580) {
    cyx = 3;
  }
  if ($(window).width() < 480) {
    cyx = 4;
  }



pls help to make this short

Comment: For future reference, always put the logic that works in the question. I've edited it for you in this case. Also, why do you need to do this? The UI and the JS should be two completely separate entities. If you're having to amend the JS code based on the size of the screen, it's an indicator that something is not being done correctly.

Comment: You can "codegolf" anything, when you say "shorter" are you just looking for suggested improvements? What you have right now isn't particularly long (for an un-minified and understandable piece of code)

Comment: What value should `cyx` contain for `$(window).width() === 780`?

Comment: I would imagine a situation where a responsive layout loads new cards. Perhaps on desktop width, you would load 6 cards at a time, but only 3 on mobile. It's not common, but I can think of times where you need to adjust your JS code depending on the UI layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
var width = $(window).width();
var cyx;

if (width > 781) {
  cyx = 4;
} else if (width > 780) {
  cyx = 3;
} else if (width > 580) {
  cyx = 2;
} else if (width > 480) {
  cyx = 1;
}
```

This is how I would do that type of logic.  You could 'shorten' it using ternaries, but it would look messy and confusing.

Comment: acctualy i have this code below working with react js but the code above is not working

below is my code


  if ($(window).width() > 789) {
    var cyx2 = 1;
  }
  if ($(window).width() < 780) {
    cyx2 = 2;
  }
  if ($(window).width() < 580) {
    cyx2 = 3;
  }
  if ($(window).width() < 480) {
    cyx2 = 4;
  }

it is very long code i want  to make it short to use it with react js 

thank you

Comment: @UISMART Why would you use jQuery for window width in React.js? You can avoid jQuery and only use React.js: https://betterprogramming.pub/usebreakpoint-hook-get-media-query-breakpoints-in-react-3f1779b73568

Answer (score 0):

You can use some math:

```
const cyx = [780, 580, 480].filter(el => el > $(window).width()).length + 1;
```

That's not exactly what the code in the question does, but it's what I assume you actually want.

Example:

```js
console.log([780, 580, 480].filter(el => el > 800).length + 1);
console.log([780, 580, 480].filter(el => el > 700).length + 1);
console.log([780, 580, 480].filter(el => el > 500).length + 1);
console.log([780, 580, 480].filter(el => el > 400).length + 1);
```

Comment: thank you for your help

yes but its working on reverse way..... and i cant control it .

its showing 1 image in large screen small screen 2, 3, 4

but i want it show 4 image in large screen then 3, 2, 1

Comment: @UISMART The code in your questions assigns 4 for `$(window).width() === 400` and 1 for `$(window).width() === 800` exactly as the code in my answer. If you asked a wrong question, you should first fix the question and then I can fix my answer.

Comment: i want 1 image in small screen in 480px

then 2 image 580px
then 3 image 768px
then 4 image 980px
then 5 image in 1280px     .......this way

please help

thank you

Comment: @UISMART Can you first fix your question? Where does the list 480px, 580px, 768px, 980px, 1280px come from? You have other values in your question.

Comment: in your code i don't  need the list. this is a very good code . but its working with reverse way as my need . so  please help me to reverse these as i describe before with a single line code

Comment: @UISMART Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform with the goal to help future users with similar problems. An answer isn't useful if it doesn't answer the question. This answer solves the problem described in your question, although you meant to ask a different question. Fix your question and I'll fix the answer. Changing my answer according to your new requirements would make this answer useless if you don't change the question.

Comment: https://357e0.csb.app/

Comment: https://357e0.csb.app/  

please check the above link in slider 1, there in small screen it showing 4 image but i need 1 image in small screen , and  in desktop it showing 1 image but in desk top i need 4 image to show and in tab 2 image i want to show. this is my need. and this time i think i ask my question properly?
thank you

Comment: @UISMART I understood your question after your first comment one hour ago, but you have to fix your question first. Edit your question, and then I will update my answer. Currently, you're wasting your time and my time. I will ignore your comments until you fix your question. In addition, your solution isn't response. The layout doesn't change when I change the size of the window. The solution in https://betterprogramming.pub/usebreakpoint-hook-get-media-query-breakpoints-in-react-3f1779b73568 is responsive.

Comment: i have updated my question and i don't want to use this  betterprogramming.pub/… 
i want to solve this like your way  .......

 const cyx = [780, 580, 480].filter(el => el > $(window).width()).length + 1;

thank you please help  and this time if my updated question is not proper  pls tell me the question it should be? i will update that.

thank you

Comment: @UISMART Your question contains the code https://jsfiddle.net/9bL25ewu/. Edit that code. You're describing the behavior at some special widths. Describe the behavior between these widths and below and above these widths.

Answer (score 0):

Another method I've done in the past is to include a 0 height div on the page. I give it an ID like `#breakpoint`. Then I set a z-index for it in the CSS stylesheet. For example:

```
#breakpoint { height:0; z-index:10; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #breakpoint { z-index:5; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    #breakpoint { z-index:1; }
}
```

Then, you simply have to measure the z-index value.

```
var bp = parseInt($("#breakpoint").css('z-index'));
switch(bp){
    case 10:
        console.log("Is mobile");
        break;
    case 5:
        console.log("Is tablet");
        break;
    case 1:
        console.log("Is desktop");
        break;
}
```

This cuts down on measurements of the window width, and you can adjust your breakpoints in the CSS code rather than defining widths in the JavaScript code.